# Confusing parameters in setTimeout method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parameters

In the following function parameters (from , to) are in px. In the code the codeline : setTimeout('slideLogo(' + from + ',' + to + ')', 75); contains so many plus signs, I am much confused here. In addition to it so many single quote signs(') are also very confusing. Please help me to clear this part.

```
function slideLogo(from, to) {
             if (from < to) {
                company.top = (from += 10);
                setTimeout('slideLogo(' + from + ',' + to + ')', 75);
            }
            else initObjects();
}
```

Comment: Please, do not use a string as the first parameter of `setTimeout`, create an anonymous function instead. `setTimeout(function (){ slideLogo(from, to); }, 75);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a plus sign is used and one of the values is a string, the plus sign concantenates the values together as a string, so in this case the strings in the variables are just concantenated into the string passed to setTimeout. Here's an example

```
var from = '10';
var to   = 40;

var fn   = 'slideLogo(' + from + ',' + to + ')'; // result == "slideLogo(10,40)"
```

However, passing a string to setTimeout is the same as eval'ing the string, and bad practice.

Preferably it should look like this

```
function slideLogo(from, to) {
     if (from < to) {

        company.top = (from += 10);
        setTimeout(function() {
            slideLogo(from, to);
        }, 75);

     } else {

        initObjects();

     }
}
```

Comment: Hi Adeneo, when I replace by this your suggested code, the script does not work, but your code has given me some more understanding of js.

Comment: @HarjitSingh - I think there was a typo, see if it works now.

Answer (score 0):

if

from = 10
and
to = 20

the code would read

```
function slideLogo(from, to) {
         if (from < to) {
            company.top = (from += 10);
            setTimeout('slideLogo(10, 20), 75);
        }
        else initObjects();
```

}

the + in the code is used as string concatinator. 
The ' delimit the hard coded pieces of strings and the + then adds the variables to that string.

Comment: Thanks Melvin. You have greatly simplified the matter for easy understanding.

Answer (score 0):

As PhistucK has mentioned in the comments, it's considered unsafe to pass in strings to `setTimeout`. You can either create an anonymous function like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  slideLogo(from, to);
}, 75);
```

Or, pass in a bound function, like this:

```
setTimeout(slideLogo.bind(null, from, to), 75);
```

Comment: HI THAMEERA, Thanks for your great suggestion. Can you send me some link to know more and in detail about bound functions.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind There is an example with `setTimeout` as well

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up your code:

```
function slideLogo(from, to) {
             if (from < to) {
                company.top = (from += 10);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    slideLogo(from, to);
                }, 75);
            }
            else initObjects();
}
```

The code contains a `setTimeout`. The first parameter of the `setTimeout` is an anonymous `function` calling your `slideLogo` `function`, passing the `from` and `to` parameters. The second parameter of the `setTimeout` is the time (`75` milliseconds) to wait before the anonymous `function` is executed.

Comment: Hi Lajos Arpad, Thanks for deep details of setTimeout() parameters.

Comment: @HarjitSingh, you are welcome, I am happy your problem is solved.